# Choose and translate value of tag

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to choose which transform will be applied based on its value.
if test is High Definition, igh efinition will be removed leaving only HD but if test is Standard onlySD will be the set value.

Source xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <file_information>
        <asset_data>
        <upn>FF074172</upn>
        <title>test</title>
        <version>High Definition</version>
        <duration>00:30</duration>
        <tc_in>23:00:00:00</tc_in>
        <tc_out>23:00:30:00</tc_out>
        <aspect_ratio>16X9</aspect_ratio>
        <segment>
            <sequence>1</sequence>
            <tc_in>23:00:00:00</tc_in>
            <tc_out>23:00:30:00</tc_out> 
            <comment></comment> 

        </segment>
        </asset_data>
    </file_information>
```

Transform

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
       <xsl:template match="/">
         <file_information>
          <asset_data>
          <upn>
          <xsl:value-of select="//upn"/>
          </upn>
          <title>
          <xsl:value-of select="//title"/>
          </title>
          <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="High Definition">
          <version>
          <xsl:value-of select="translate(//version,'igh efinition','')"/>
          </version>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
          <version>
          <xsl:value-of select="translate(//version,'tandard','D',)"/>
          </version>
          </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
          <duration>
          <xsl:value-of select="//duration"/>
          </duration>
          <tc_in>
          <xsl:value-of select="//tc_in"/>
          </tc_in>
          <tc_out>
          <xsl:value-of select="//tc_out"/>
          </tc_out>
          <aspect_ratio>
       <xsl:value-of select="translate(//aspect_ratio,'X',':')"/>
    </aspect_ratio>
  </asset_data>
</file_information>
```

Expected Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <file_information>
        <asset_data>
        <upn>FF074172</upn>
        <title>test</title>
        <version>HD</version>
        <duration>00:30</duration>
        <tc_in>23:00:00:00</tc_in>
        <tc_out>23:00:30:00</tc_out>
        <aspect_ratio>16:9</aspect_ratio>
        <segment>
            <sequence>1</sequence>
            <tc_in>23:00:00:00</tc_in>
            <tc_out>23:00:30:00</tc_out> 
            <comment></comment> 
        </segment>
        </asset_data>
    </file_information>
```

or

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <file_information>
        <asset_data>
        <upn>FF074172</upn>
        <title>test</title>
        <version>SD</version>
        <duration>00:30</duration>
        <tc_in>23:00:00:00</tc_in>
        <tc_out>23:00:30:00</tc_out>
        <aspect_ratio>16:9</aspect_ratio>
        <segment>
            <sequence>1</sequence>
            <tc_in>23:00:00:00</tc_in>
            <tc_out>23:00:30:00</tc_out> 
            <comment></comment> 
        </segment>
        </asset_data>
    </file_information>
```

Do you know what is going wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks guys!
this solved my issue (= instead eq,translate instead replace):

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()"><!--Identity template-->
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="version">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test=". = 'High Definition'">
            <version><xsl:value-of select="'HD'"/></version>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <version><xsl:value-of select="'SD'"/></version>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="aspect_ratio">
      <xsl:element name="{name()}">
         <xsl:value-of select="translate(., 'X', ':')"/>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Here I used IDENTITY template, which will results all nodes to output, then I used selective match, for ex. 'version' and 'aspect_ratio' elements.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()"><!--Identity template-->
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="version">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test=". eq 'High Definition'">
            <version><xsl:value-of select="'HD'"/></version>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <version><xsl:value-of select="'SD'"/></version>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="aspect_ratio">
      <xsl:element name="{name()}">
         <xsl:value-of select="replace(., 'X', ':')"/>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: As it is, this is a XSLT 2.0 answer (even though the version is set to 1.0).

Comment: Change <xsl:when test="High Definition"> to <xsl:when test="//version eq 'High Definition'"> and <xsl:value-of select="translate(//version,'tandard','D',)"/> to <xsl:value-of select="translate(//version,'tandard','D')"/> (comma after 'D' removed)